# Animate CGPath in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uibezierpath, skspritenode, cgpath

I am making a game with SpriteKit where there is a boy character. I decided to use a curved line for his arms and legs. I want to be able to animate his arms and legs by bending the line. Is there any way I can achieve animation of a line in SpriteKit? And how can I do it?

Comment: A lot of ways actually...just use search... take a look at this for start : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32309474/3402095

Comment: Another way to handle animations is to create the character using software such as "After Effects". Then export the animation as a series of PNG's and use SpriteKit's SKTexture Atlases to animate a node.