# Generating random terrain in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

First of all I want to mention that I have no deep knowledge about games or SpriteKit framework (however, I have good programming skills).

I want to create a 2D game for iPhone and iPads. So far, I know that I have to use SpriteKit. However, the most import of this game is the terrain. I should be able to generate it dynamically so it will have curves (but not spike edges) like the black line from the attached image. Also, I would like to have the down part of ground in two separate layers (one thin layer of green to simulate grass and the rest some brownish color to simulate dirt), but this is something nice to have.

Also I would like to know how can I "explode" a little portion of ground when something (like an cannon ball) touches it.

Can someone explain or guide me on how can I achieve this?

[image: example of random generated ground]

Thank you!

Comment: I see two questions here: 1. How to work with tile maps and 2. How to do an "explode" animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Map Generation

There are two approaches that you can try here:

1. The `SKTileMapNode` class in `SpriteKit`
2. The `CGPath` class(es) in CoreGraphics.

#### The SpriteKit Approach

Start by taking a look at `SpriteKit`'s tile map features. There's a class called [`SKTileMapNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktilemapnode) that can help you make a tile-based side or top-down view of your game world.

Apple introduced this at WWDC 2016, and [the session video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/610/) is a good starting point for that. Xcode has a good editor for setting up your tile maps, including variations on specific tiles (called "Tile Variants") and adding metadata to your tiles. All of that is going to be helpful here.

You can define pre-built groups of tiles as [`SKTileGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktilegroup)s, for things like two sides of a hill that only make sense next to each other. It might be simple enough to do that and then generate some random combinations. You could then use different variants to show "exploded" tiles.

> The preferred method to create tile groups is to use the editor tools in Xcode. However, should you wish to work with SpriteKit’s tile support programmatically, the following examples discuss the necessary steps.
>
> -- [Apple Documentation, `SKTileGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktilegroup)

Accordingly, you can use [`SKTileGroupRule`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktilegrouprule) can help you define rules about where to put tiles relative to each other *programmatically*.

Here's [a tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/137216/whats-new-spritekit-ios-10-look-tile-maps) from Ray Wenderlich that takes you through the basics of a tile-based game. Here's [another RayWenderlich.com tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/49502/procedural-level-generation-in-games-tutorial-part-1) that discusses procedural level generation.

#### The CGPath Approach

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305978/spritekit-generate-random-curl-line?rq=1) discusses a similar situation where someone asked about drawing curves for use with SpriteKit. It shows some code for generating randomized bezier curves, and links to [a second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432255/224988) with an in-depth discussion of CoreGraphics' handling of adding paths to bezier curves.

## Explosions

For exploding a tile, have a look at [`SKEmitterNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skemitternode). Xcode includes an emitter editor, and you can do some cool stuff with it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it pretty much covers all my questions. However, by "explode"I meant removing a little bit of ground in a semi-cricle shape. Can you also give me some clues on how can I achieve that?

Comment: Again, multiple options: 1. Look at `SKCropNode` 2. You can try to use multiple tile variants.

Comment: you can also use `GKNoise` apparently to do terrain as well. In one of the wwdc videos from last year @Alec